# Why do I need to set a value of a component when assigning a state from event handler?

Tags: reactjs

I'm new to react and just following some tutorials, I can't find the answer to this

Given state `input` and `submit` in my component, these 2 inputs gave me the same result to change the `state.submit`

```
<input value = {this.state.input} onChange = {this.handleChange.bind(this)}/>
```

```
<input onChange = {this.handleChange.bind(this)}/>
```

Why do i still need to set the `value = {this.state.input}` if the `handleChange` function already set the state with the given events?

Example below to handle the submitted value

```
handleChange(e){
   this.setState({
    input: e.target.value,
   })
}

handleSubmit(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  this.setState((state)=>({
    submit: state.input
  }));
}
```

If i return a form that uses `handleSubmit` to change a header with `submit` state, both of them returns the same value

Can anyone help me to explain?

Thanks

Comment: React is almost similar to vanilla when it comes to events. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/change_event

Answer (score 4):

React has taken control of rendering DOM elements, every html element will be binded with a value in component's state. when there is a change in value react re-renders the component. Which means a setState will trigger rendering the component again. and as far as the event handler is considered , its just invoking an handler and nothing to do with updating the state. we have to update the state when onChange handler is called.

Comment: But then how come the value of `state.input` was changed without me assigning the value? Doesn't that mean that assigning event handler to change `state.input` when i'm typing to the input assigns the value to the state itself? I updated my question too if you don't mind..

Comment: you are already changing state.input in handleChange onChange event handler, the same value you are using in handleSubmit method, by the way when you are invoking handleSubmit method ?